# Determining group of covering transformations

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

We let $p: E \to X$ be the covering map
 shown here:

[image: here.]

I'm having trouble figuring out the group of covering transformations. How do we go about doing that in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe some covering transformations, at least? Can you tell what a covering transformation must do with the double points?